# Replacing string character in python

Tags: python

I am making a program where the user inputs some text, and I wan't all the characters in that text that is not in the variable "alfabet" to be changed to "?". How can I do this? I also want a to do it in two functions, main and clean_text. My code looks like this now:

```
def clean_text():
for char in text:
if char in alfabeth:
continue
elif char not in alfabeth:
#don't know what to do here
#text[] = "?"

def main():
userInput = input("type in text: ")
text = list(userInput)

if__name__ == "__main__":
main()
clean_text(text)
```

Comment: Note: I get the error message "NameError: name 'text' is not defined" when I run the program and give an input

Comment: Your code has many errors. If this is your complete code, then it cannot run, fix typos, indentation first. And then what is alfabet? You have not defined. For replacing read [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm)

Comment: Yeah I know the code has errors. My main question is how to use a for loop to run through characters in a string, and then replace specific characters. "Alfabet" is alfabeth in norwegian, sorry about that. I want to change every character that is not in alfabeth, into "?".

Comment: I didn't mean what is the meaning of Alfabet, I asked if it's a list or a variable. And for how to use loops on a string, you can search in Google for tutorials.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Ohh my bad. I forgot to put it in the question. I did it like this:
alfabeth = "abcd......."
alfabethList = list(alfabeth)

so it's a list

Comment: For saving our time when reading please indent your python code as mentioned above.

Comment: Your function definition is not receiving any argument any argument `text`, that is the reason for your error, I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the basic code you need:

```
alfabeth = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

text_in = list(input('What ever'))

for x in range(len(text_in)):
    if text_in[x] in alfabeth:
        continue
    else:
        text_in[x] = '?'

text_in = "".join(text_in)        
print(text_in)
```

If you want you can define everything as one function or two or what ever you like. 
Hope it helps

This is how it can look with functions. It worked for me.

```
alfabeth = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def clean_text(text_in, alfabeth):
    for x in range(len(text_in)):
        if text_in[x] in alfabeth:
            continue
        else:
            text_in[x] = '?'

def main():
    global UsrInput
    UsrInput = list(input('type in text: '))
    return UsrInput

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    clean_text(UsrInput, alfabeth)
print("".join(UsrInput))
```

Comment: yesssss u genius!! thank you so much. is there any way to do it without the global variable? my school want us to avoid that as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

You have to return something to be able to assign that `user_input` to a variable to pass into `clean_text()`. Here is a working version of your project.  This will handle multiple words separated by space as well.

```
def clean_text(word):
    alphabeth = 'vshthstmpd'
    for idx, item in enumerate(word):
        if item == ' ':
            pass
        elif item not in alphabeth:
            word[idx] = '?'
    return ''.join(word)

def main():
    user_input = input('Type in text: ')
    text = list(user_input)
    return text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = main()
    print(clean_text(text))
```

> ```
> Type in text: vash the stampede
> v?sh th? st?mp?d?
> ```